# Conway's Game of Life python

Tags: python, game-of-life

It's my implementation.  Can I get some opinions on it?

```
import random
import os
import time

class Game:

 def __init__(self, turns, w, h):
    self.board = []

    for x in range(0, h):
        self.board.append([])
        for y in range(0, w):
            self.board[x].append(random.random())

    self.turns = turns

 def next_gen(self):
    self.board_next = []

    for x in range(0, len(self.board)):
        self.board_next.append([])

    for x in range(0, len(self.board)):
        for y in range(0, len(self.board[x])):
            n = 0

            for dx in range(-1, 2):
                for dy in range(-1, 2):
                    if (dx == 0 and dy == 0):
                        pass
                    else:
                        try:
                            if (x + dx >= 0 and y + dy >= 0):
                                if (self.board[x + dx][y + dy]):
                                    n += 1
                        except IndexError:
                            pass

            c = self.board[x][y]

            if (n == 1 or n == 0):
                c = 0
            elif (n == 3):
                c = 1
            elif (n == 2):
                pass
            else:
                c = 0

            self.board_next[x].append(c)

    self.board = self.board_next[:]

 def show(self):
    for x in range(0, len(self.board)):
        l = ""
        for y in range(0, len(self.board[x])):
            if (self.board[x][y]):
                l += "X"
            else:
                l += "#"
        print(l)
    time.sleep(0.5)

 def start(self):
    for x in range(0, self.turns):
        print("\n+Gen {0}".format(x + 1))
        self.show()
        if (x + 1 != self.turns):
            os.system('clear')
        self.next_gen()

os.system('clear')
game = Game(3, 3, 3)
game.board = [
      [0, 0, 0],
      [1, 1, 1],
      [0, 0, 0]]
game.start()
```

And output:

```
+Gen 1
###
XXX
###

+Gen 2 
#X# 
#X#
#X#

+Gen 3
###
XXX
###
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First three general remarks:

1. `range` does not need an explicit start argument, it defaults to 0. `range` is basically `range(start=0, stop, step=1)`, only `stop` is needed
2. `if` takes an expression as argument which just has to evaluate truthy or falsey. There is no need for parenthesis, unless chaining multiple expressions over multiple lines or doing some complicated `and`/`or` logic.
3. you should consistently use 4 spaces per indentation level (your class only has 2 in the outer level).

---

Your setting up of the board can be simplified with a list comprehension:

```
self.board = [[random.random() for _ in range(w)] for _ in range(h)]
```

Here I used `_` as an unused loop variable, as customary in Python.

I would also save `h` and `w` in the class for later use.

---

In `Game.next_gen`:

```
if (n == 1 or n == 0):
    c = 0
elif (n == 3):
    c = 1
elif (n == 2):
    pass
else:
    c = 0
```

is equivalent to:

```
if n == 3:
    c = 1
elif n != 2:
    c = 0
```

I would make two helper functions calculating neighbours that are alive:

```
def neighbours(self, x, y):
    p = -1, 0, 1
    for dx, dy in itertools.product(p, p)
        if dx == dy == 0:
            continue
        _x, _y = x + dx, y + dy
        if 0 <= _x < self.h and 0 <= _y < self.w:
            yield _x, _y

def alive_neighbours(self, x, y):
    return sum(self.board[n_x][n_y] > 0 for n_x, n_y in self.neighbours(x, y))
```

Here I used the boundaries to make sure that `neighbours` only serves points inside the grid (and used `itertools.product` to make it easier to construct `dx` and `dy`). Then getting the sum of all alive neighbours just sums over the values, since in `self.board` empty cells have a value of zero, while alive cells a value greater than zero.

This simplifies `next_gen` to:

```
def next_gen(self):
   board_next = [[0 for _ in range(self.w)] * self.h]
   for x in range(len(self.board)):
       for y in range(len(self.board[x])):
           n = self.alive_neighbours(x, y)
           cell = self.board[x][y]
           if n == 3:
              cell = 1
           elif n != 2:
              cell = 0
           board_next[x][y] = cell
   self.board = board_next[:]
```

---

Your `show` function can be simplified using `str.join`:

```
def show(self):
   for row in self.board:
       print("".join("X" if cell else "#" for cell in row))
```

The `time.sleep(0.5)` I would put in `start` to make it possible to show the generation without delay if necessary.

---

I would put the code calling your class into a `if __name__ == "__main__":` guard to allow importing your class from another module:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.system('clear')
    game = Game(3, 3, 3)
    game.board = [
      [0, 0, 0],
      [1, 1, 1],
      [0, 0, 0]]
    game.start()
```